# A peculiar crosstab query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have read a few of these questions and answers when it comes to put a crosstab query into SQL Server. I tried doing this but I got errors.

The simple example is as is I have a barcode on a package of m&m's I want a SQL Server pivot table if you will that will take this information below and turn it into a query that shows the row headers as the barcode, and the column headers as the different colors.

I have a qry/table that has

```
| Package Barcode | Color | SomNmr
| 12345           | BLUE  | 3
| 12345           | RED   | 3
| 12345           | YELL  | 3
| 19999           | BLUE  | 24
| 19999           | BLUE  | 24
| 19999           | PINK  | 24
| 19999           | RED   | 24
| 19999           | RED   | 24
```

When I run a crosstab query wizard, I run it with the following options:

*Which Fields values do you want as row headings?*

I select **Package Barcode**

*Which Fields values do you want as column headings?*

I choose **Color**

*What number do you want calculated for each column and row intersection?*

I choose **SomNmr** and the Function of **COUNT**

The crosstab pulls exactly what I was looking for:

[image: picture of my crosstab]

I looked at the SQL code and paste it into SQL Server Management Studio but I get some errors.

```
TRANSFORM Count(Table1.[SomNmr]) AS CountOfSomNmr
SELECT Table1.[Package Barcode], Count(Table1.[SomNmr]) AS [Total Of SomNmr]
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.[Package Barcode]
PIVOT Table1.[Color];
```

How do I go about getting this to work on SQL Server? I was looking around and reading about using case when but I can't seem to apply that correctly to make it work. Any help appreciated.

I made a video in depth explaining what I have if anyone would like to see it I will find out how to post it on here.

Comment: Investigate `PIVOT` in SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you Kamil! I will definitely go digging deeper into this. Been watching quite a few youtube videos already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need DYNAMIC

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Color) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Package Barcode],[Total],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select [Package Barcode],B.[Color],B.[Cnt]
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Color=A.Color,Cnt=1
                        Union All
                        Select Color=''Total'',Cnt=1
                     ) B
       ) A
 Pivot (Sum(Cnt) For [Color] in ([Total],' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Package Barcode Total   BLUE    PINK    RED YELL
12345           3       1       NULL    1   1
19999           5       2       1       2   NULL
```

> **EDIT - If it helps, the SQL Generates looks like this**

```
 Select [Package Barcode],[Total],[BLUE],[PINK],[RED],[YELL]
  From (
        Select [Package Barcode],B.[Color],B.[Cnt]
         From  YourTable A
         Cross Apply (
                        Select Color=A.Color,Cnt=1
                        Union All
                        Select Color='Total',Cnt=1
                     ) B
       ) A
 Pivot (Sum(Cnt) For [Color] in ([Total],[BLUE],[PINK],[RED],[YELL]) ) p
```

> **EDIT 2**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Color) From YourTable Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
 Select [Package Barcode],[Total],' + @SQL + '
  From (
        Select [Package Barcode],[Color],[Cnt]=case when Sum(Cnt)=0 then ''>>'' else cast(Sum(Cnt) as nvarchar(25)) end
         From  (
                Select [Package Barcode],[Color],[Cnt]=Sum(1) from YourTable Group By [Package Barcode],[Color]
                Union ALL
                Select Distinct [Package Barcode],C.[Color],[Cnt]=0
                 From  YourTable
                 Cross Join (Select Distinct Color From YourTable) C
                Union All
                Select [Package Barcode],[Color]=''Total'',[Cnt]=Sum(1) from YourTable Group By [Package Barcode]
               ) A
        Group By [Package Barcode],[Color]
       ) A
 Pivot (max(Cnt) For [Color] in ([Total],' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Package Barcode Total   BLUE    PINK    RED YELL
12345           3       1       >>      1   1
19999           5       2       1       2   >>
```

Having trouble getting → to display, so I put a >> as a place marker.

> **Edit 3 - Conditional Aggregation**

```
Select [Package Barcode]
      ,[Total] = sum(1)
      ,[BLUE]  = sum(case when color='Blue' then 1 else 0 end)
      ,[Pink]  = sum(case when color='Pink' then 1 else 0 end)
      --.. Add more colors
 From YourTable 
 Group By [Package Barcode]
```

Comment: Thank you John! this worked for me! Thank you kindly.

Comment: @vladyerus Happy to help.

Comment: In your formula, I keep trying to use coalesce or Isnull in order to provide a value of 0 for the Null values, but it doesn't seem to work anywhere I put it.

Comment: @vladyerus So you want to display NULLs as zero?

Comment: I do not have access to my data since it is at home, but essentially I want the Column returns if null to be ChrW(8594).

Comment: In my Access database I had `Nz(Count([myTable].[Color]),ChrW(8594)) AS CountOfColor` and it would return something like: 
`RED   | BLUE  
1          |  →`

Comment: Sorry The last portion of my message didn't get formatted correctly, but to clarify, essentially If a Barcode didn't have any RED in it, I want the value on the crosstab to be `→` which is ChrW(8594)

Comment: @vladyerus In SQ: Server. you would be mixing data types.  That said we can do a conversion and present the cnt as a varchar() and this would allow your ChrW(8594) .   Honestly, this belongs in the presentation layer, but I will amend my answer in a few

Comment: Thanks @John. I am only starting to Sql and Database Administration but just by playing around with the code I have learned a lot. You're knowledge only bolsters and expands my knowledge base and keeps my motivation going to continue finding the right Computer Science field for me. So Thank you.

Comment: @vladyerus You're very welcome.  That's why we're here :)

Comment: I forgot to mention but you probably likely know, when you edit the answer can you edit the one under "EDIT - If it helps, the SQL Generates looks like this" , this is the one I used and am familiar with.

Comment: @vladyerus See Update

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you!! I hope to come to the point where one day I am providing the same assistance on here as you provided for me today.

Comment: @vladyerus Once again, you are very welcome.   Just keep an eye on this site,  I learn something new every day.  That's the fun part

Comment: With your code, the execute works and is flawless but when I try to save the query, It throws up a 'Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'Declare'
When I hover over it, it states something to the effect of : Expecting '(', or SELECT WITH

Comment: @vladyerus When you say "Save It", stored Procedure or are you trying to save it as a view?

Comment: Saving it as a view

Comment: @vladyerus Nope, not possible.  Views don't support dynamic SQL.  It can be a Stored Procedure.  BUT, IF YOU NEED it as a view, and the COLORS don't change (much or often), you can you can Select {at}SQL to see the code generated, and save that as a view.  CAUTION: If a new color is added tomorrow, you will have to update the view

Comment: The Colors stay the same. There are a total of 11 in the table. they do not change thankfully!

Comment: @vladyerus Good news, you don't need dynamic.  Then save the generated SQL as your view.

Comment: I hope you do not think I am just fishing to have the work done for me, I am literally trying everything you say, but I do not quite understand what you mean by Select {at} SQL do you mean Script View As - Select To?

Comment: On top of trying what you say I am googling and searching like a madman through these forums and trying other things.

Comment: @vladyerus Not at all, this is how we lean by working with a real-world problems

Comment: so how do I go about

Comment: @vladyerus Had I known you only had 11 colors, a conditional aggregation would have done the trick as well

Comment: woops. How do I go about 'Select {at} Sql to see the generated code?

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry I should have stated clearly exactly what I was building up to.

Comment: @vladyerus Replace Exec({at}SQL) with Print {at}SQL

Comment: @vladyerus See Edit 3

Comment: Holy smokes It is really that simple? I will test it out after this meeting and let you know! Cheers.

Comment: @vladyerus I should have asked.  Just assumed you had a large number of colors